# Parse JSON using amirdew/JSON library

Tags: android, json

I'm using `amirdew/JSON` library, which [you can find here](https://github.com/amirdew/JSON) to parse my string to JSON.
The string I retrieved is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Portugal

This is the code I have at the moment, and it is not working and I believe that it is because of the keys...

```
public void ParseJson (String json){
JSON json2 = new JSON(json);

String firstTag = json2.key("query").key("pages").key("extract").stringValue();
txtInfo = findViewById(R.id.txtInfo);
txtInfo.setText(firstTag);
}
```

The `firstTag` variable is null because it can't retrieve any value. I want to retrieve the text inside "**extracts**". How can I do it? What keys do I need?

Comment: I think it's because you are missing the actual `pageid` which is `23033` in your case. try `json2.key("query").key("pages").key("23033").key("extract").stringValue();`

Comment: And how can I retrieve that pageid and store it ina  variable? I mean, if I search "Portugal" the pageId is 23033 but, if I search "Spain", the page id will change...

Comment: Then what you should do is just search for `json2.key("query").key("pages")` which will return you an array of different `pageid` and you can iterate over them to get each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use the `JSONObject` which is already inside the [SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject). You would use it like this:

```
String input = "..."; // your input
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(input);
Strings extracts = obj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("pages").getJSONObject("23033").getString("extract");
```

Comment: Oh, but what if that `getJSONObject("23033")` is variable? I mean, this happens when I search "Portugal", but, if I search "Spain" the number will change...

Comment: You can call the `names()` function on the `JSONObject` to get back the string names in this object, and then retrieve the `JSONObject` with the name found. Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names()).

Comment: If this isn't asking much, can you update your question with the solution? I'm trying to get it but I can't find it ahah

Comment: I mean, I can get the pageId but it is like `"["1480"]"`. I need just the "1480", how can I remove the "[]" ?

Comment: The returned object is a `JSONArray`. You call the `get(int index)` method on it to retrieve the first value. Therefore you would call `someObj.get(0)` to get out  `"1480"`.  Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray).